# Why Repeater ItemCommand Doesn't fire, even if i don't rebind by post back?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, itemcommand

As title you see, I Have problem with firing itemcommand(nothing happened).
before evry thing, let me tell you i take a look to all forums and stackoverflow questions like these :

[Repeater ItemCommand Doesn't fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510976/repeater-itemcommand-doesnt-fire)

[ItemCommand of Repeater is not fire with LinkButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814456/itemcommand-of-repeater-)

But I Still Have Problem With this, so please just take a look to my code and guid me.

**My ASPX Code is:**

```
<div class="span4">
                    <aside class="left-sidebar">
                        <div class="widget">
                            <div class="input-append">
                                <input class="span2" id="SearchPhrase" type="text" placeholder="Type a Phrase" maxlength="20" runat="server" />
                                <asp:Button ID="AppendedInputButton" runat="server" class="btn btn-color" OnClick="AppendedInputButton_Click" Text="Search" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget">
                            <h5 class="widgetheading">Categories</h5>
                            <ul class="cat">
                                <asp:Repeater ID="RPTCategories" runat="server" DataSourceID="SDSCategories">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <li><i class='icon-angle-right'></i>&nbsp
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HLCategories" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/En/News/{0}/{1}",Eval("CategoryId"),Eval("CategoryName").ToString().Replace(" ","-")) %>'><%#Eval("CategoryName")%></asp:HyperLink>
                                            <sub>&nbsp(<%# Eval("PostsCount") %>)&nbsp</sub></li>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SDSCategories" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT C.CategoryId,CategoryName,COUNT(P.CategoryId) as PostsCount FROM TblCategory C left join TblPost P ON C.CategoryId=P.CategoryId AND C.Deleted <> 'True' AND P.Deleted <> 'True' GROUP BY CategoryName,C.CategoryId ORDER BY CategoryName ASC" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionCS %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget">
                            <h5 class="widgetheading">Recent posts</h5>
                            <ul class="cat">
                                <asp:Repeater ID="RPTRecentPosts" runat="server" DataSourceID="SDSRecentPosts">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <li><i class='icon-angle-right'></i>&nbsp
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HLRecentPosts" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/En/Post/{0}/{1}",Eval("PostId"),Eval("Title").ToString().Replace(" ","-")) %>'><%#Eval("Title")%></asp:HyperLink>
                                            <sub>&nbsp(<%# Eval("SubmitDate") %>)&nbsp</sub></li>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SDSRecentPosts" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 5 PostId,Title,SubmitDate FROM TblPost Order BY PostId DESC" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionCS %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </aside>
                </div>

<div class="span8">
      <asp:Repeater ID="RPTPosts" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
       <br />
       <article>
       <div class="row">
       <div class="span8">
       <div class="post-heading">
       <h3>
       <asp:HyperLink ID="HLPostTitle" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/En/Post/{0}/{1}",Eval("PostId"),Eval("Title").ToString().Replace(" ","-")) %>'><%#Eval("Title")%></asp:HyperLink>
       </h3>
       </div>

       <div class="post-image">
       <asp:Image ID="IMGPostImage" runat="server" AlternateText='<%#Eval("Title") %>' ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ImageUrl='<%# "~/Image/Blogs/"+ Eval("ImageName")%>' />
       </div>
       <div class="meta-post">
       <a href="#" class="author">By<br />Admin</a>
       <asp:HyperLink ID="HLPostDate" CssClass="date" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/En/News/{0}",Eval("SubmitDate").ToString().Replace("/","-"))%>'><%# Eval("SubmitDate", "{0:d/MMMM}") %><br />
       <%# Eval("SubmitTime") %></asp:HyperLink>
       <br />
       <i class="icon-tags"></i>
       <p class="keywords" runat="server" id="KeyWords"><%# Eval("Kewords").ToString().Replace(","," - ")%></p>
       </div>

       <div class="post-entry">
       <div class="subtext">
       <%# Eval("MainText").ToString() %>
       </div>
       <br />
       <asp:HyperLink ID="PostLink" runat="server" CssClass="read-more" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/En/Post/{0}/{1}",Eval("PostId"),Eval("Title").ToString().Replace(" ","-")) %>'>Read more about&nbsp<%#Eval("Title")%></asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </article>
        <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

      <div id="pagination">
      <span class="all" runat="server" id="CurrentPage">Total Pages</span>
      <asp:Repeater ID="RPTPaging" runat="server" Visible="false" OnItemDataBound="RPTPaging_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="RPTPaging_ItemCommand" >
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnPage" CssClass="inactive" CommandName="Page"  CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>"></asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
       </div>
```

**And Here My C# Code IS :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls;

namespace KamSln.En
{
    public partial class News : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DBQuerys DBQ = new DBQuerys();
        Funcs Fn = new Funcs();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                NewsPagedData();
            }
        }
        protected void AppendedInputButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/En/Search/" + SearchPhrase.Value.ToString());
        }
        protected void RPTPaging_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["PageNumber"] = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            NewsPagedData();
        }
        public int CurrentPageNumber
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["PageNumber"] != null)
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["PageNumber"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["PageNumber"] = value;
            }
        }
        private void NewsPagedData()
        {
            DataTable dt = GetNews();
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            PagedDataSource pagedItems = new PagedDataSource();
            pagedItems.DataSource = dv;
            pagedItems.AllowPaging = true;
            pagedItems.PageSize = 1;
            pagedItems.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPageNumber - 1;
            ViewState["PageNumber"] = CurrentPageNumber;

            int rowsCount = dv.Table.Rows.Count;
            int totalPages = rowsCount / 1;
            if (totalPages > 1)
            {
                RPTPaging.Visible = true;
                CurrentPage.Visible = true;
                System.Collections.ArrayList pages = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
                for (int i = 0; i < totalPages; i++)
                    pages.Add((i + 1).ToString());
                RPTPaging.DataSource = pages;
                RPTPaging.DataBind();

            }
            else
            {
                RPTPaging.Visible = false;
                CurrentPage.Visible = false;
            }
            CurrentPage.InnerText = "Page " + CurrentPageNumber + " of " + totalPages;
            RPTPosts.DataSource = pagedItems;
            RPTPosts.DataBind();
        }
        protected void RPTPaging_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("BtnPage");
            if (!Fn.ValidityCheck(lb.Text, "MightNull") && ViewState["PageNumber"] != null)
                if (ViewState["PageNumber"].ToString() == lb.Text)
                    lb.CssClass = "current";

        }
        private DataTable GetNews()
        {
            DataTable NewsTable = new DataTable();
            NewsTable = DBQ.PostsList(null, 'A', null, null);
            if (Page.RouteData.Values.Count > 0)
            {
                string FRdatta = Page.RouteData.Values.Keys.First().ToString();
                if (Page.RouteData.Values[FRdatta].ToString() != "En")
                {
                    switch (Page.RouteData.Values.Keys.First())
                    {
                        case "ci": NewsTable = DBQ.PostsList(Page.RouteData.Values["ci"].ToString(), 'C', null, null); break;
                        case "pd": NewsTable = DBQ.PostsList(null, 'D', Page.RouteData.Values["pd"].ToString(), null); break;
                        case "sf": NewsTable = DBQ.PostsList(null, 'T', null, Page.RouteData.Values["sf"].ToString());
                            foreach (DataRow row in NewsTable.Rows)
                            {
                                row["Title"] = row["Title"].ToString().Replace(Page.RouteData.Values["sf"].ToString(), "<span style='color:blue;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;'>" + Page.RouteData.Values["sf"].ToString() + "</span>");
                                row["MainText"] = row["MainText"].ToString().Replace(Page.RouteData.Values["sf"].ToString(), "<span style='color:blue;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;'>" + Page.RouteData.Values["sf"].ToString() + "</span>");
                            }
                            break;
                        default: NewsTable = DBQ.PostsList(null, 'A', null, null); break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return NewsTable;
        }




    }
}
```

is-not-fire-with-linkbutton

Comment: Most idiotic thing you do is to downvote answer for your own mistake. You corrected your question because of that answer but still downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Try using click event of a LinkButton, instead of `OnItemCommand`. You can access LinkButton using below code in Click Event.

```
LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)Sender;
```

OR

```
LinkButton lb = Sender as LinkButton;
```

Comment: I Tried This Before,this also Not fired Unfortunately

Comment: I tried to execute your `RPTPaging` code, it worked fine for me.

Comment: let me mention this:
i have two repeater else upper this code,they bind automaticlly by datasource.wish to see code?

Comment: Please Just Take a look at my aspx code again.thanks for your help

Comment: I Found That the page changed but if i click in nother control in page. like an input button. after page refreshed. the page is changed true

Comment: Are you using `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: I feel like there you missed logic in `NewsPagedData` method. Try to debug it by using breakpoints.

Comment: I Did before. nothing wrong. evry thing just goes right

Comment: You have set clicked linkbuttons number to CurrentPageIndex,instead you are written following code. `pagedItems.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPageNumber - 1;`. This is the problem.

Comment: i ignore that function and that  code line before..but nothing changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87461/discussion-between-sushmit-patil-and-amin).

Answer (score 1):

Dear Expert After 2 day finally i figure out why my page doesn't post back. after i tried to post back my button manually with java script and i failed. i tried to trace the script and i found this Error with firebug:

```
 TypeError: theForm.submit is not a function
     theForm.submit();
```

when i google it i found i have a button in my MasterPage with id="Submit" and as "submit is not a function" means that you named your submit button or some other element submit. Rename the button to btnSubmit and your call will magically work.

When you name the button submit, you override the submit() function on the form.

So This Problem Resolved. Thanks to all.